# Change indented multiline string in file in terminal

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

i want to change multiline string within particular marks that is indented in file, example looks like this:

```
    non_important_array: [
    text
    ],
    important_array: [
    text1,
    text2,
    text3
    ],
    non_important_array: [
    text
    ],
```

my goal is to be able to replace `important_array` with my multiline string

```
    my_array: [
    my_text1,
    my_text2
    ],
```

so i would like to have it like so:

```
    non_important_array: [
    text
    ],
    my_array: [
    my_text1,
    my_text2
    ],
    non_important_array: [
    text
    ],
```

but there could be also a variation, and it will look like this:

```
    non_important_array: [text],
    important_array: [text1,text2,text3],
    non_important_array: [text],
```

and the output should be looking similar as expected above

```
    non_important_array: [text],
    my_array: [
    my_text1,
    my_text2
    ],
    non_important_array: [text],
```

Right now im trying to make this work with `sed`, but it's taking last occurance of `]` and i dont know how to correct that

```
sed -i '' '/\s*important_array.*/,/\]/c\
    my_array: [\
    my_text1,\
    my_text2\
    ],' file.txt
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

- one liner would be much appreciated
- i want to replace it inplace, to have the same file modified

Comment: The 2 requirements you added as edits are likely to get you fewer answers as most people would consider them irrelevant compared to the things that actually matter about software such as clarity, robustness, efficiency, and portability and be concerned about how you'll prioritize a good answer vs  a "one liner" that does "inplace" edits. For example, I wouldn't have bothered answering had those been present in your question at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    new = new $0 ORS
    next
}
/^[[:space:]]*important_array:[[:space:]]*\[/ {
    inBlock = 1
    printf "%s", new
}
inBlock {
    if ( /^[[:space:]]*],/ ) {
        inBlock = 0
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
    non_important_array: [
    text
    ],
    my_array: [
    my_text1,
    my_text2
    ],
    non_important_array: [
    text
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

#### sulution 1: `awk` script:

```
 awk '{sub("[[:space:]]important_array:"," my_array:")}1' ORS="]," RS="]," input.txt
```

##### Output:

```
non_important_array: [
text
],
my_array: [
text1,
text2,
text3
],
non_important_array: [
text
],
```

#### sulution 2: `awk` script:

```
 awk '
  BEGIN{ORS="],\n"; RS="],"; FS="\n"; OFS=" "}
  {
    sub("[[:space:]]important_array:"," my_array:");
    gsub("[[:space:]]+"," ");
    $1=$1;
 }1' input.txt
```

##### Output:

```
 non_important_array: [ text ],
 my_array: [ text1, text2, text3 ],
 non_important_array: [ text ],
```

Comment: You should mention those require GNU awk for multi-char RS. Neither solution produces the desired output though.

Answer (score 0):

First test without the `-i` flag.
I think your problem is `\s*`, any number of whitespace, so also matches `non_`.
When you wan to use `sed`, try

```
sed -r '/\s+important_array.*/,/\]/c\
  my_array: [\
  my_text1,\
  my_text2\
  ],' file.txt
```